# Is there an equivalent of Python's __file__ in Emacs Lisp

Tags: file, emacs, elisp

Is there a way for an Emacs lisp file (.el) to get its own file name?

Like `__file__` in Python or `__FILE__` in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do the job:

```
(setq hhh load-file-name)

(defun aoeuidhtn ()
  (interactive)
  (message hhh)
)
```

Now, after doing `M-x load-file` variable `hhh` will be bound to a filename in which it resides and function `M-x aoeuidhtn` will print it. For example, if I had the above module in `/tmp/test.el` then `M-x aoeuidhnt` would print `/tmp/test.el`.